# Why is Node.js npm so very slow on my Windows 10 computer

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, windows-10, nodejs-server

I just started following the tutorial for ReactJs using Node create-react-app.

I am developing this in Visual Studio Code.

When I run npm start, it is 3-5 minutes before the server is started up, and that seems very slow.

I saw many tips on here that said to add it to windows defender as an exclusion from real-time protection, but that did not work for me.

I saw some tips about disabling IPv6, and that also did not work.

Anything else I should check?

This is on a Windows 10 Pro installation.

```
> npm version
{
  npm: '6.14.4',
  ares: '1.16.0',
  brotli: '1.0.7',
  cldr: '37.0',
  http_parser: '2.9.3',
  icu: '67.1',
  llhttp: '2.0.4',
  modules: '72',
  napi: '6',
  nghttp2: '1.41.0',
  node: '12.18.0',
  openssl: '1.1.1g',
  tz: '2019c',
  unicode: '13.0',
  uv: '1.37.0',
  v8: '7.8.279.23-node.37',
  zlib: '1.2.11'
}
```

```
>systeminfo

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.18363 N/A Build 18363
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the problem was very simple, and I wanted to make sure other people would have the this post when searching in the future.

I had accidentally created my VS Code workspace on a Samba drive, and so it was pulling all the modules over the network.

I moved that to my SSD and, to nobodies surprise, it started working as expected.